# increase the upload limit of HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

When using HAProxy, I've been getting the error `413: Request Entity Too Large`

This error occurs when I'm trying to upload some files which are too large, however I can not find any documentation on how to increase this limit.

How can you increase the maximum upload limit to a specified amount of MB's?

Comment: Haproxy has nothing to do with the upload limit

Comment: Odd must be from the docker registry behind haproxy. I've had success with the same image without the proxy though .. ?

Comment: Try adding these to your haproxy config: `tune.maxrewrite 16384
    tune.bufsize 32768`, one per line

Comment: yes I'll let you know

Comment: turns out this was cloudflare in front of my haproxy.. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a HAProxy error, as you can see here http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.7#1.3.1, **413** Error is not in the list.
So this probably an error returned from the server and HAProxy is just "forwarding" the error to the client.
To be 100% sure, you can see the logs:

- An error returned by HAProxy:

  ```
  127.0.0.1:35494 fe_main be_app/websrv1 0/0/-1/-1/3002 503 212 - - SC-- 0/0/0/0/3 0/0 "GET /test HTTP/1.1"
  ```
- An error returned by the backend server:

  ```
   127.0.0.1:39055 fe_main be_app/websrv2 0/0/0/0/0 404 324 - - --NI 1/1/0/1/0 0/0 "GET /test HTTP/1.1"
  ```

Notice the "-1" in the timers.